# SSIS - Extract multiple databases based on lookup table

Tags: sql, ssis, lookup, extract

How do I create a package that extracts multiple databases(and all tables in each database) from another server based on a lookup table (also found on the other server) that contains a column where all the databases I need to extract is listed ?

I need to use the lookup table because new databases is created from time to time on the source, so I cannot just create a job that extracts a "static set" of databases to a destination. It needs to be a bit dynamic...

Furthermore I also need to extract the databases incremental where I can use a timestamp that exists in all databases/tables.

Im new to SSIS, so an "easy" guide would be appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, what you're asking for isn't an "easy" thing.

Comment: Could you provide the schema and some sample data of this table that describes the databases and such that need to be autoreplicated? How about the timestamp attribute, could you describe in more detail how that should factor into ETL

Comment: But still possible using SSIS? Any articles etc. I can read to understand the concept and challenges ?

Comment: I'll try to get some more info tomorrow since most info is on remote servers...

Comment: The biggest hurdle you will run into is that SSIS uses a concept of a data flow to move data from source to sink. That data flow can provide great performance but that comes at a cost that your metadata must be fixed before the package runs. You can't have the *same* dataflow pull a 2 column lookup table and a 100 column customer tombstone table by just changing the name of the source table. SSIS will need to know that metadata beforehand so it can allocate memory correctly.

Comment: You would therefore need to design lots of data flow tasks, either in an enormous package or preferably split out into smaller, more manageable packages. This package creation can be automated through things like Biml, EzAPI, etc but it's still going to take work. Then once you have the basics of the packages built out, you'll need to worry about the logic of source system date is 2013-06-26 and destination is as of 2013-05-31. Find the changeset per table and then add all the new data and test for changes/deletes to existing data. If destination and source have changed, what's correct?

Comment: This isn't a bad question, just there's a lot of scenarios to work out. SSIS may or may not be the right tool. Heck, something like a replication, plain old backup and restore, MS Synch framework, etc might be a better solution but until you've really laid out how this will work, how much time it will take to implement it in X technology versus the various costs involved, it's hard to say "Go here"

Comment: I see, I also came to the same conclusion that the metadata is the biggest hurdle because it's not fixed, so that's why I had to ask in a forum... I actually also looked into the replication

Comment: but I have to read a bit more about that before I go for that solution. But then there is the issue that the source server is validated, meaning if I set up a replication solution I probably need to do a lot of documentation or somebody have to. But can you configure replication to replicate instance to instance (so that I don't have to worry about new databses) and incremental at the same time?

Comment: Not possible to do something like this then?                      1. Scheduler job imports metadata from external server
2. metadata is populated into a temp database
3. Scheduler job extracts data based on metadata found in temp      database
4. The Scheduler job also extracts the data incremental using a    timestamp found in all tables

Answer (score 0):

As a rough idea, you could work with SSIS Package Configurations and executing packages from within packages, and then use the Transfer SQL Server Objects Task:

- Make a "Main package" that iterates over the column in your lookup table.
- For each entry, it should UPDATE the Package Config entry of your second SSIS package accordingly. Use the "SQL Server" configuration for that second package.
- The Main package should then execute the second package - there is a also a task for this.
- The second package looks at its config to find out which server to get databases from and uses the Transfer SQL Server Objects Task to do so.
- then the Main package continues with the next entry from your lookup table.

Ideally you would want to have your "second SSIS package" inside SQL Server's MSDB rather than the file system. Its easier to execute.

Comment: Cheers, I'll what I can come up with :)